# Visual Basic Multiple Button to show Mulitple Picturebox/Richtext

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vbscript

So here's what I want. When i click on a button it will show 1 PictureBox and 1 RichtextBox (Which is btw Visible=False so that it will not show unless clicked when the program is opened) as you can see here on my screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2aft.png)

But when I click other button it doesn't change it stays with the first button i clicked when i opened the program. I really don't know the code since I'm new with VB.

Here's the code I used:

```
    Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        PictureBox1.Visible = True
        RichTextBox1.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        PictureBox2.Visible = True
        RichTextBox2.Visible = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Your non-question is unclear - if you want visibility to change from set1 yo set2, you need to also make the first set invisible.

Comment: Do not vandalise your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Since (I guess) both of the images are right on top of each other, you need to set the first image to invisible again. If not controlled which image is on top depends on the order the images where added.

You could do something like this :

```
Private Sub hideElements()
    For i as Integer = 1 to 6
        Me.Controls("PictureBox" & i).Visible = False
        Me.Controls("RichTextBox" & i).Visible = False
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Call hideElements()

    PictureBox1.Visible = True
    RichTextBox1.Visible = True
End Sub
```

This loop sets all PictureBox1 - Picturebox6 and RichtextBox1 - RichTextBox6 to invisible, now you can set the one you want to show to visible.

So just call **hideElements** at the beginning of all of your button handler.

If u want to change the amount of images/richtextboxes, you only need to adjust the **6** in the loop.

Hope I could help.